# Trigger to Update picklist value based child records picklist value

Tags: trigger, workflow

I have two custom objects  Sale__c and Project__c.  Both Sale__c and Project__c have different status in a picklist.   Sale__c status is broken into two picklist Status__c and Status Detail__c  Project has one status proect_status__c.

I am looking to create a trigger that updates the Sales status and status detail to "Net" (status) "completed" (status detail)  when all related projects in a sale have a status of "completed"   I only want the status and detail to change if the status is already NOT "final" or "paid in full" OR status detail NOT "invoiced"

I have tried to do this with a simple workflow rule and field update, but have not had any luck.

Comment: What is the relationship between Sale__c and Project__c?

Comment: it appears to be a lookup relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to first figure out whether or not all projects have status 'completed'. To do that, you need 2 roll-up summary fields on Sale__c.

1. Number_of_projects__c which just counts the number of projects linked to the Sale
2. Number_of_completed_projects__c which counts the number of projects with status 'Completed'

Note that this will only work if the relationship is Master-Detail. If it isn't, you will have to either change it to Master-Detail or revert to an APEX trigger.

Then, based on the contents of the 2 roll-up fields, you can create a workflow rule on Sale that checks the current Sale status and substatus. If those are allright, then check if the 2 roll-up fields are equal (and you might want to check that they are >0 as well). If all of those prerequiresites are OK, then update the Sale status and substatus.

Comment: That would work, however i believe the relationship is a lookup relationship.  It is a part of a manage package.  So changing the relationship is not an option.

Comment: @KevinCampopiano I'm sure this is no longer an open issue, but you can use [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to accomplish rollups through a lookup relationship.